Prediction intervals for multiple regression on log-log transformed data
I am making models for biomass estimates of trees with ordinary least squares linear multiple regression on log-log transformed data. In the end I would like to get a prediction of biomass with prediction interval in the original scale. I have read several posts on the topic (here and elsewhere) without getting wiser. I am a novice in statistics and would appreciate some hands-on advice. Here is what I know:
I expect the relationship of my independent variables ($x_i$) and the independent variable ($y$) to be a power function. The regression is performed on log-log transformed data like this:
$$\ln(y)=\alpha+\beta_1\ln(x_1)+\dots+\beta_n \ln(x_n)$$
I realize that I need a correction factor to get an unbiased estimate and have check for constant variance and normal distribution of the residuals so an estimate should look like this:
$$\hat y=e^{a+b_1 \ln(x_1)+\dots +b_n \ln(x_n)+\hat\sigma^2/2}$$
where $a$ and $b_i$ are coefficients from the regression and $\hat\sigma$ is the standard error of the residuals.
So far so good (I hope!). What I want is a PI for my $\hat y$ (i.e. an equation specifying a range wherein 95% of future observations will fall, in kg units). I suspect that the transformation and the fact that the error is no independent from $y$ could case some complications. Reading on the topic just makes me confused. I have two guesses:

Calculating the PI of ${\ln(y)}$ from the regression, adding ${\hat\sigma^2/2}$ and back-transforming it.
Calculate a new error estimate from: $s=\sqrt{{1\over{N-p}}\sum{(\hat y-y_{obs})^2}}$ and use this to calculate a PI, but then I guess that heteroscedasticity will be a problem.

Comments and references that will improve my understanding is of course appreciated but what I really need is a clear method that will give me a statistically valid result. And GLM is not an option for me in this case.
The reason for insisting on OLS, rather than using GLM is simply because it is (yet) the most commonly used method of the field.
As requested I add the residual plots. 

Welcome to Cross Validated! Why isn't a GLM (e.g., Gamma or Gaussian with log links) an option? A GLM can be a good choice, depending on whether/how residual errors are associated with outcome values. Please edit the question to explain that, and also to show quality-control plots of your current model that show the overall distributions of residuals and the residuals as a function of your model-predicted values. Those details are necessary to ensure that an answer about prediction intervals would be helpful and correct.

I'm a little worried about the three labeled outliers, but this could have been a lot worse. So I've answered the question under the assumption that the requirements for reliable linear regression (in the log-transformed outcome scale) were met. Do look into GLMs for your own benefit; the fact that something else is commonly used in your field doesn't necessarily mean it's the best choice.

I added to my answer to show problems with getting reliable CI/PI for the "corrected" estimate in the original biomass scale. CI/PI are typically used to show the precision of model predictions. If your model is in the log scale of outcome, then it's best to work in thelog(biomass) scale for that, as that's the scale in which regression gives you the best linear unbiased estimates. It sounds from a comment that you intend to use back-transformed biomass values and CI/PI for some downstream modeling. If so, post a new question about that downstream work; there might be a better approach.

The trick here, as in many other situations with transformed data, is to work in a scale where you have something close to a normal distribution until the very end. Only then reverse the transformation. Here, that means working with outcomes and outcome predictions in the scale of $\ln y$, under the assumption that your model in the log-transformed scale meets the linear regression assumptions. The log transformations of the predictors don't matter provided that you transform them appropriately before making predictions.
This answer shows the formulas for the confidence interval (CI, for the estimate of the mean response) and the prediction interval (PI, for a single new observation) in multiple linear regression as a function of the vector of new predictor values $x_0$. Below, $\hat{y}_0$ is the outcome estimate in the scale of the linear regression ($\widehat{\ln y_0} $ in your situation) at the predictor values in $x_0$, $X$ is the $n \times p$ design matrix of the original multiple regression, and $\hat \sigma$ is the square root of the modeled estimate of the error variance. Copying from there (with some rearrangement and editing):

CI for the mean response given $x_0$: $$\hat{y}_0 \pm t_{n-p}^{(\alpha/2)}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0}$$
PI for a single future response for $x_0$: $$\hat{y}_0 \pm t_{n-p}^{(\alpha/2)}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0 + 1}$$
Where $t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2}$ is a t-statistic with $n-p$ degrees of
freedom at the $\alpha/2$ quantile.

There are a few things to keep in mind.
First, with more than one predictor variable in the regression, there is no single PI or CI. Both depend on the particular vector of predictor values, $x_0$, that you want to use for your prediction. You will not get a single "equation specifying a range wherein 95% of future observations will fall, in kg units." You will get an expression for the PI or CI that depends on your choice of the elements of $x_0$.
Second, the variance of the PI starts with the variance of the CI for the estimated mean $(\hat{\sigma}^2 x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0)$ and then adds the estimated error variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$ to get the variance of the PI. That's OK here, as the mean and variance are independent when linear regression meets the necessary assumptions. For both CI and PI, you then take the square root of the corresponding variance to get the standard error, and multiply the standard error by the t-statistic that takes into account the number of observations $n$ underlying the estimates of the $p$ coefficients at your desired confidence/prediction level.
Third, the intervals aren't simply calculated from the variances of the individual coefficient estimates; the formula is a bit more complicated than for simple linear regression with a single predictor variable. The intervals depend on the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates, $\hat{\sigma}^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$. To avoid errors, let well-vetted software do the calculations. For a standard lm() linear regression model in R, the corresponding predict() function can provide either CI or PI depending on your choice between "confidence" and "prediction" for the interval argument.
Fourth, as you used log-transformed outcome values to get your predictions, do the above calculations in that log-transformed scale first to get CI and PI in the log-transformed scale. Do the inverse transformation, putting the point estimates and interval boundaries into the original scale, only at the end.
These course notes also show the formulas for CI and PI in multiple linear regression, and contain an example of getting CI and PI for multiple linear regression with a log-transformed outcome variable on pages 16-17. The back transformations are the very last things that are done.
In response to comments
In a comment, you say:

my main aim is to use the model to predict biomass on other trees. Since these predictions will be used in further research it would be preferable to express them in mean, original scale.

That suggests that there might be a bit of an "XY problem" here. If you are going to use predictions from this model as a basis for further modeling, there might be better ways to proceed. Consider asking a new question that includes the proposed downstream uses of the current model predictions and how their CI/PI would come into play.
If your primary interest is in the arithmetic mean outcome in the original scale, I think that current practice would be to use a GLM, for example a gamma GLM with a log link based on the same assumption of a constant coefficient of variation as linear regression on log-transformed outcomes.
As an intellectual exercise, I'll continue with implications of the bias correction for CI and PI, and some associated cautions.
The factor $\exp (\hat{\sigma}^2/2)$ in the formula for $\hat y$ in the OP is an attempt to correct for the bias between the arithmetic mean and the result obtained by exponentiating a prediction from the linear regression of a log-transformed outcome. It was described by Miller, The American Statistician 38: 124-126 (1984).
That had some usefulness 40 years ago, when working scientists in applied fields might have lacked understanding of the then fairly recent developments in generalized linear models and when it was much more difficult and expensive than today to have access to well-vetted, efficient software for statistical analysis. (I now look back with some horror at the linear regressions with transformed variables that I did during my PhD work 50 years ago, when I only had access to a Texas Instruments programmable hand-held calculator.)
Miller's correction for bias, however, also contains a bias, as acknowledged on page 125 of the paper. Quoting from an answer by Ben to a question about that correction:

The OLS coefficient estimators [on the log-transformed outcomes] and corresponding error-variance estimator are unbiased for their respective parameters under standard model conditions. However, since you are substituting the estimator into an exponential, any overestimation is going to be exacerbated by the exponential and any underestimation is going to be mitigated. This means that your estimated mean response is generally going to be a positively biased estimator of the true mean response...

Ben adds: "The above results are all predicated on the assumption that the log-linear model form is correct." That's a critical assumption. In that context, your outliers distorting the normal q-q plot and pulling down the residuals near the middle of the residuals versus fitted plot become more troubling.
If you nevertheless want to pursue the implications of the Miller bias correction for CI and PI in the original scale, work as above in the log-transformed scale until the very last step. Take the log of your proposed $\hat y$ estimator and rewrite compactly in vector-matrix form with a predictor vector $x_0$ to get the formula for the point estimate in the log-transformed scale:
$$\ln \hat y_0 = x_0^T \hat \beta + \frac{\hat \sigma^2}{2}.$$
As the mean and variance in the linear regression are independent if necessary assumptions are met, the variance of that estimator in the log scale is the sum of the variance of the two terms. The variance of the first term is as given above, $\hat{\sigma}^2 x_0^T (X^TX)^{-1} x_0$. If the error distribution is normal, then an estimate of the variance of a variance estimate, based on $n-p$ degrees of freedom, could be $2 \hat \sigma^4/(n-p)$. Thus one might use the following for the variance of the point estimate used for getting CI in the log-transformed scale:
$$\text{Var} (\ln \hat y_0) = \hat{\sigma}^2 x_0^T (X^TX)^{-1} x_0 + \frac{\hat \sigma^4}{2(n-p)}.$$
A first level correction to get the variance of the "bias-corrected" PI would be to add the residual variance $\hat \sigma^2$ to the above. But as $\text{Var}(A+B)=\text{Var}(A)+\text{Var}(B)+2\text{Cov}(A,B)$, I think that you might need to add a term for the covariance between $\hat\sigma^2$ and $\hat\sigma^4$. (See this page for the covariance between $x$ and $x^2$.) I'm also not sure that the result would have the underlying normal distribution assumed in using a t-distribution to get the CI or PI from the square root of the estimated variance. Again, only exponentiate at the very end to get back to the original scale.
Finally, the farther you go down this road the more reliant you become on the assumptions underlying the linear regression on log-transformed variables.

A big +1.  The "$\hat\sigma^2/2$" term undoubtedly arose from a (misguided) attempt to apply the formula for the arithmetic mean of a lognormal distribution, suggesting the key concept to focus on concerns when and when not to apply such an adjustment to a statistical estimate.  Many people seem to be confused about that.

Very helpful EdM! I will certainly use available functions for calculations. ̂²/2 has to do with the arithmetic mean, indeed, and one of the reasons I seek guidance here. When I apply it the the estimated y it definitely helps closing in on the observed y. So if I understand it correctly: If I want to predict a mean of new trees I apply the correction factor to the fit before back-transforming. But the correction factor should not be applied to the prediction interval, which simply can be back-transformed after calculated? That is if I am satisfied with the assumptions.

@bio_chas I'm not clear what you mean by "correction factor." You should NOT be using anything like $\sigma^2/2$ as a "correction factor." If by "correction factor" you mean the difference between the CI for the mean value and the PI for an individual new prediction, then the correct way to get the PI is to work in the log-transformed scale, add the variance of the CI to the residual estimated variance $\hat \sigma^2$, then take the square root, multiply by the appropriate t-value, use that to get differences from the point estimate in the log scale, and back-transform at the end.

@bio_chas If you want to predict the mean value for a new tree in the usual sense, you should be using a GLM with a log link. You are modeling the mean of the logarithms of the outcomes, from which back-transforming gives the geometric mean. There's nothing wrong with that, but it's critical to be clear and to understand the difference.

The correction factor I am using is discussed here. For what I have seen this I common practice in tree allometry, but obviously not perfect.  @whuber Would you like to elaborate on when I it is applicable and not.

The correction applies to estimates of arithmetic means.  As @Ed has explained, all you're doing is expressing values on a log scale and comparing them.  Because the logarithm is a strictly increasing one-to-one function, the result of a comparison of logarithms is always identical to a comparison of the original values and vice versa.

@whuber I am not sure I understand. By comparing, do you mean dealing with the variance and PI etc.? I think I understand why I should not use any correction in this case. But my main aim is to use the model to predict biomass on other trees. Since these predictions will be used in further research it would be preferable to express them in mean, original scale. Is it not appropriate to use a correction in this case?

I mean simply comparing in the usual sense of the word, as expressed by the mathematical symbols "$\gt$" and "$\lt.$"  You write of a "prediction interval." Such intervals are employed by comparing some value (the predictand) to the endpoints of the interval.  That's all there is to it.
